# VSBuild task not able to find vsVersion ='14.0'

Tags: azure-devops

In one of my pipeline, I am trying to build a solution which is created using VS2015. I am using a on-prem agent.

I am using VSBuild task as shown below

```
 - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '**\*.sln'
        vsVersion: '14.0'
        configuration: 'release'
        clean: true
```

When I run this pipeline, in the logs I can see this warning

##[warning]Visual Studio version '14.0' not found. Falling back to version '16.0'.

Do I have to install something more in the agent? Agent capability is showing me multiple MSBuild versions

[image: Agent capability]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio version 14.0 referes to Visual Stuido 2015 which is not installed on you agents based on this screenshot. So if you want to use this, you need install if on your agent.

Comment: As per VSBuild@1 doco, it says that it internally use MSBuild. And I can see MSBuild ver 14.0 installed in the agent. Am I supposed to install full Visual studio (with license) in the agent?